# Мореман - происхождение слова

Tags: словообразование

Меня интересует происхождение слова **мореман**.

По сути - это составное слово из **море** (русск.) и **man** (англ.)

Но, почему тогда мы произносим - **мореман**, а не **моремэн**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мореман - слово одесского происхождения (во всяком случае, оно фигурирует в сборниках одесских фразеологизмов), обозначает моряка торгового флота. Я слышал, что так называют себя и курсанты мореходных училищ. В быту так говорят просто о людях, имеющих отношение к флоту или увлечённых морской тематикой. Прямого английского аналога у слова нет, поэтому нет причин произносить "мен". "Ман" при словообразовании часто происходит от 'mania' (меломан), поэтому здесь окончание несёт оттенок "увлечённости морем", которую принято ассоциировать с моряками. Возможно, слово возникло под влиянием похожих на "море" созвучий в иностранных словах, которые в Одессе были на слуху, напр., по-итальянски море 'mare', в английском есть слово 'maritime' (морской) и т. д.
Что ещё напоминает такое русско-нерусское словообразование? Прежде всего, "морепродукты" (сокращение от "морские продукты") - для меня оно звучит излишне канцелярски, в отличие от "мореман". Совсем коряво, на мой взгляд, таким способом образовано слово "танцпол" (перелопаченное 'dance floor') - своей неблагозвучностью заставляет вспомнить грибоедовское "смешение французского с нижегородским".

Comment: Спасибо, Александр!

Answer (score 1):

Да, в основе второй части этого сленгового образование лежит английское "man", но основательно обрусевшее и потерявшее качество "Э" в гласном.

Вот на примере морского жаргона:
~~~~~~   
Среди имен существительных со значением лица выделяется также группа слов, образованных от именных и глагольных основ при помощи иноязычного структурного элемента -ман- (от английского man - "человек")[12]: группа > группман - "командир организационного подразделения (группы) боевой части или службы корабля", кореш[13] > корешман - "близкий товарищ, друг; соплаватель; собутыльник", море > мореман - "отличный моряк, опытный моряк, 'морской волк'"[14],ухать >ухман  
~~~~~~   
http://www.kalanov.ru/index.php?id=184

Кстати, прямая связь с английским опровергается еще и тем, что в английском подобные образования на -man имеют весьма ограниченную сферу применения, А seaman имеет множество значений, из которых "моряк" далеко не главное (опускаю подробности, тут надо обращаться к многочисленным пиджинам и койне).

С другой стороны, в голландском, например, откуда "пошла есть" современная морская терминология, гласный в "man" сохранил свое качество обычного "А". Так что "ман" вполне объяснимо.

Наконец, стоит упомянуть, что "мореман" фиксируется не только собственно "морскими" словниками, но и словарями уголовного жаргона.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Слово мореман состоит из двух слов, море и мания. Человек, которого манит море. Как правило истинные моряки "болеют" морем, не могут долго без него обходиться, море "зовёт", поэтому моряков, любящих свою работу, зовут мореманами.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, я не совсем согласен. Слово "мореман" носит, скорее, несколько ироничный характер. Это человек, который хочет больше казаться моряком, чем он есть на самом деле. Это брюки клеш, шириной с черное море, походка в раскорячку, ну, и пр. А моряки себя могут назвать мореманом только в шутку. Причем, палуба себя, почти официально, называет "моряками". Ну, а мы в машине попроще))))